# PHP exec won't execute shell commands

Tags: php, html

My code:

```
<?php
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $dir=$_POST['dir'];
        $link=$_POST['link'];
    exec('echo "'.$link.'" > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
        exec('wget -P '.$dir.' -b -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt -o /www/wget.log -c -t 100 -w 10',$out);
        echo $out[2];
        exit();
    }
echo "<br><br><form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Download directory :<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Download link :<br>';
echo ("<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"11\" cols=\"60\"></textarea><br><br>");
echo '<input type="submit" name="wget-send" value="Send" />';
echo "</form></div>";

foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

It works, wget will download the urls given but after I click the submit button it shows nothing, only a blank page, but when I change this part:

```
echo "<br><br><form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
```

to be like this

```
echo "<br><br><form action=wget_log.php method=\"post\">";
```

or any php/html files, wget won't do anything but it'll redirect me to the next page, what I'd like to do is have that wget run and go to `wget_log.php` after I click the submit button, here's my `wget_log.php` file:

```
<?php
header("refresh: 5;");
include 'theme.php';
ceklogin();
css();
echo " Wget log :<br>";
echo "<textarea name=\"text-info\" rows=\"30\" cols=\"90\" readonly style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 7pt;\" >";
$datalines = file ("wget.log");
foreach ($datalines as $zz) {
echo $zz; }
echo "</textarea></div>";
foot();
echo '

</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

@GolezTrol, I did what you suggested and put the string here:

```
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $dir=$_POST['dir'];
        $link=$_POST['link'];
        exec('echo "'.$link.'" > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
        exec('wget -P '.$dir.' -b -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt -o /www/wget.log -c -t 100 -w 10',$out);
        echo $out[2];
        header('Location: wget_log.php');
        exit();
    }

echo "<br><br><form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
```

But I get this error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/wget.php:1) in /www/wget.php on line 12`

**Update 2**

```
<?php
header('Location: wget_log.php');
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $dir=$_POST['dir'];
        $link=$_POST['link'];
    exec('echo "'.$link.'" > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
        exec('wget -P '.$dir.' -b -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt -o /www/wget.log -c -t 100 -w 10',$out);
        /*echo $out[2];*/
        exit();
    }
echo "<br><br><form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Download directory :<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Download link :<br>';
echo ("<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"11\" cols=\"60\"></textarea><br><br>");
echo '<input type="submit" name="wget-send" value="Send" />';
echo "</form></div>";

foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

I edited my code like that but still get the following error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/wget.php:1) in /www/wget.php on line 2`

Comment: Does apache has write permissions on `/www/` ? Does your solution (writing into temporary file the link, then using that file as wget input) required? Maybe there is better way to do this in php.

Comment: when I type in some texts and hit submit, the log at /www/wget.log is updating so I guess it has the permission, am I wrong?

Comment: Side note: I hope it's just simplified code for the site. You're basically running a shell with any arbitrary code submitted by site users.

Comment: One suggestion I have is changing $PHP_SELF to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Comment: Please don't post the same question over and over again. Rather think about what people tell you. It will help you to solve your questions !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fetching the content of the redirect page and echoing it, you can perform whatever you need to do, and then redirect using the location header:

```
header('Location: wget_log.php');
```

This is known as the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

The header should be the first thing you output in your script, and of course you only must do it when you save the file, otherwise you will want to show the form and not redirect at all. So the structure of the code should look like this. I left out the code that does the actual saving for brevity. Core thing is: for the `Location` header (or any header) to work, it must be the first thing that is outputted, so there should be no HTML or even whitespace before the `<?php` opening tag, and there must be no other echoes or prints before the header either, or calls to other functions that echo something.

```
<?php

if($_POST['wget-send']) {
  // Save the File here..

  // Then redirect and terminate this script.
  header('Location: wget_log.php');
  exit();
}

// Normal page rendering in case of no file:
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();

// Form goes here.
```

Comment: I get this `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/wget.php:1) in /www/wget.php on line 12` Please see my updated post above

Comment: @orlea You need to do the redirect before you send any other output.

Comment: if you do what @GolezTrol suggested, you have to comment or remove the `echo $out[2];` If you echoed something, you cannot modify header information (what `header` does to make the redirection)

Comment: I still get the error guys, please take a look at my updated post again.

Comment: Is there any whitespace before the `<?php` opening tag?

Comment: No, I double checked that

Comment: @GolezTrol I updated the script with the one you just edited above but it still gives me `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/wget.php:1) in /www/wget.php on line 19` do I have to change this part?
`echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\" id=\"WgetForm\">";` 
If I do, what should I change it to?

Comment: *"Output started at wget.php:1"*. That message is quite clear, there is some output on line 1 of wget.php. Did you accidentally save the PHP as UTF-8 with BOM? In that case there will be an (mostly invisible) 3 byte mark at the start of the file.